# Combining two object in javascript and convert to String

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, variables

I am hoping I am missing something obvious here, but I have tried for the past half day to set two variables to combine in a certain format in Javascript I can do it as a string, however I need it in a different format.

If I select on option from the check boxes `{"GILLS":"7"}` works fine however if two options are selected `query1` should look like  `[{"GILLS":"1"},{"GILLS":"7"}]`. I cannot use += to the variable as this kicks out an unexpected token error.

```
var Query1 = '';
var Query3 = '';

if ($('input[name=checkbox2a]:checked').length > 0) {
  var  Query3 = {"GILLS":"7"};
}

if ($('input[name=checkbox2b]:checked').length > 0) {
  var Query3 = {"GILLS":"1"};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
  var Query1 = [];
```

and in your function use

```
Query1.push({"GILLS":"1"})
```

So the change will be like below

```
var Query1 = [];
var Query3 = [];

if ($('input[name=checkbox2a]:checked').length > 0) {
    Query3.push({"GILLS":"7"});
}
if ($('input[name=checkbox2b]:checked').length > 0) {
    Query3.push({"GILLS":"1"});                    
}
```

then you can use join will give you string

```
Query3.join(", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array out of Query3, if you still want a string at the end, use .join("").

```
var Query1 = '';
var Query3 = [];

if ($('input[name=checkbox2a]:checked').length > 0) {
  Query3.push({"GILLS":"7"});
}

if ($('input[name=checkbox2b]:checked').length > 0) {
  Query3.push({"GILLS":"1"});                    
}

Query3 = Query3.join(""); // back to string, if you so like
```

Answer (score 0):

You're causing pain for yourself if you take the approach that sometimes the variable is of type Object (`{"GILLS": "1" }`) and sometimes it is of type List (`[{"GILLS":"1"},{"GILLS":"7"}]`).

Since it *sometimes* needs to be a list, make sure it's *always* a list. Even though sometimes it's a list of length 1. Then when you are reading that value, you never need conditional logic to deal with two potential types.

So, it's always a List:

```
var query3 = [];
```

... and then it's easy to manipulate:

```
if(...) {
    query3.push( { "GILLS": "7" } );
}
if(...) {
    query3.push( { "GILLS": "1" } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you are declaring same variable in a different scope. Don't do this unless uou know what you are doing. In other words use `var` keyword only once for a variable in a "space" when you are using this particular variable.

An advantage/disadvantage (chose one ;)) of javascript is that there is no type control. If You type `var Query3 = '';` and then `Query3 = {"GILLS":"7"};` interpreter will execute this without any complaints beside that there is high probability, that this is not exactly what you want to do ;). In this case it makes variable `Query3` an empty string and then makes it an object.

In Your case, You want to have in result an array of objects. At first declare `var Query3=[];` and then use a push method on it (`Query3.push({});`) to add elements.